# Only return Object if if-condition is fulfilled, else no return is needed

Tags: if-statement

In the following code a Packet (Object) should be returned wen its `timeServing` is 0.

Else, the `timeServing` should be reduced by 1. The problem is that in this case nothing should be returned. Can I somehow implement this, or is this impossible ?

```
public Packet Serve()
    {
        if(timeServing == 0)
        {
          Packet p = queue.dequeue();
          timeServing = distrServ.getSample();
        }
        else
        {
            --timeServing;
        }
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return **null** depending on the language your programming in this might have a different name (e.g. **nil**)